# Difference between ISP access and LAN access

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, lan

In my book it says that:

> The access network is the network that physically connects an end system to the first router (edge router).

While also:

> A local area network (LAN) is used to connect an end system to the edge router.

Which sounds very much the same, so what's the difference between them?

I have done googleing, and by looking at some of the picture, it seems almost like LAN is the Ethernet that is the first step for the end systems to go through before they reach the first router. But are both the Ethernet and the first router considered to be the ISP access? Or is it just the first router and not the Ethernet that is considered to be the ISP access?

Comment: ISP is **I**nternet **S**ervice **P**rovider. LAN is **L**ocal **A**rea **N**etwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISP implies internet service; LAN implies *local* area. So, you might have a company with three offices. All of which might be connected to a "metro" area network, with only one office providing internet connectivity (say to at&t).

Basically, if your network is publicly routable then it is connected to the internet. But not every network is publicly routable (or even connected to the internet), see also [NIPRNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIPRNet).

Comment: Just to double check, that the one office providing internet connectivity is the ISP access? While the other three offices are in the LAN access? And the other two offices will connect to the one office with ISP through LAN?

Comment: Technically, that was called a MAN when I learned the terminology - let's try a slightly different approach, the LAN is what local machines connect to. For example, your office printer is on the LAN - it does not require a router hop to reach. Google is on the public internet, it does require a router hop (or more) to reach. It's thus on an ISP link. Anything connected to an ISP is Internet traffic (for the most part). Local machines connect to the router on a LAN port, but a router has more than one port (and it routes messages between them). So the second (or third, or more) connects to ...

Comment: a different network, which might be local - or might be a long distance line.

Comment: Ah, things are staring to clear up! But just to double check again, so the computer is connected to LAN, and when it wants to reach Google it has to go through both the LAN and ISP, and if it wants to send an email to another computer it has to go through all three: LAN, ISP and access network?

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity: if my computer were to send a request to print something to the office printer, would that request have to go through LAN and would that be considered a router hop?

Comment: @Bonbon For email, it depends... in a company, there might be an email server on the LAN. But then yes, the message itself has to route through an ISP. And not if your computer is on the same LAN as the office printer. A network switch is not (always) a router. If you look at the back of a consumer grade network router, you'll typically find that is has WIFI, a few LAN ports and a WAN port. The WAN port is an ISP link, and the LAN and WIFI are local. You could then plug a switch into one of the LAN ports and have more local network capacity.

Comment: Thank you so much!